# Trying to start a new service - but having a permission problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-services

**The error:**

I get a popup window when trying to manually start the windows service. It says:

> Windows could not start the XXX
>   service on Local Computer. Error:
>   1069: The service did not start due to
>   a logon failure.

**Post-build events:**

There are 2 Windows services in the solution and they have the same post-build events:

```
REM C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe /u  "$(TargetPath)"
REM C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe /i /username=.\administrator /password=blabla "$(TargetPath)"
```

But for some reason it's only the first service that is installed during debug-build mode. The other is not (despite similar post-build events). So I manually used the InstallUtil with the administrator login and blabla password from the post-build events. That did install it, but one is installed with "Log On As = Local System" (works!) and the other has "Log On As = .\administrator" (does not work!).

I guess that's what triggers the error. Why the difference? Is there another install going on the solution build somewhere? It should be said that it is a solution consisting of 47 projects.

Comment: Are you running VS under an Admin account? Just wondering if you can't use admin permissions (ie the username and password) when you yourself are not an admin...

Comment: I run VS as an Admin, yes. Else the build process would fail with gacutil and maybe some other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm 99% sure that you can solve this by granting the [Log on as service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739424%28WS.10%29.aspx) privilege to the administrator user.